# mongodb aggregate that inserts an array into an existing array of a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document in mongodb, like this one:

```
{ "_id" : "a", "array" : [ { "aa" : "11", "bb" : "22" } ] }
```

I want to insert an array in the array above, so the result looks like:

```
{"_id":"a","array":[{"aa":"11","bb":"22","cc":[{mm:"11"},{mm:"22"}]}]}
```

I am writing a node.js program and using the mongojs module to connect to mongodb. I have tried using `db.collection.aggregate({"$unwind":"$name"})`, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: did you try using $push to add the array field  ?db.collection.update( { _id: "a" }, { $push: { array: {[{mm:"11"},{mm:"22"}]}}})

Comment: The Aggregation framework is mean for reading data, but you appear to want to write to the document. Can you clarify exactly what you are looking to do? Do you want to add `cc` to the array in the document in the database or only during a read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update document then used `update` with [push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as below

```
db.collectionName.update(
  {"_id":"a"},
  {
    "$push":{
      "array":{
      "cc":[
        {"mm":"11"},
        {"mm":"22"}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Or if you want to add new field in aggregation then use `project` with [literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$project":{
    "array":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$array",
        "as":"el",
        "in":{
          "aa":"$$el.aa",
          "bb":"$$el.bb",
          "cc":{
            "$literal":[
              {"mm":"11"},
              {"mm":"22"}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: My only concern here is `$project` doesn't actually add to the document in the database, just to the document returned. It is essentially ephemeral.

Comment: @PeteGarafano So for this I was created two different query if OP want to update document then update work if want only in aggregation then aggregation ;), because OP not mentioned here to update document or not ?

Comment: I agree, OP's needs are unclear, I have commented asking for clarification

Comment: @Yogesh As PeteGarafano comment, 'Aggregation' is mean for reading, howerver as my code showed, I want to write the document. but if I type your code, the mongo console show:
{ "_id" : "a", "array" : [ { "aa" : "11", "bb" : "22" }, { "cc" : [ { "mm" : "11" }, { "mm" : "22" } ] } ] }
what I mean is {"_id":"a","array":[{"aa":"11","bb":"22","cc":[{mm:"11"},{mm:"22"}]}]}
I want to insert a array in first item of the  array in the  document.
thanks your answer~

Comment: @all  thanks everyone, I already solve this question with db.course.update({_id:1},{"$addToSet":{"arr.0.content":"ok"}})
Again thank you Yogesh and PeteGarafano time to reply my question